# iOS Cordova Safari - keyboard makes floating button dissapear

Tags: ios, css, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on a project with Cordova, Ionic v1, and AngularJS 1.5. cordova-ios v 5

I have a floating button in my project. It works great for everything except when I have a form page with a text input. When the iOS keyboard appears my floating button dissapears. It works fine on Android.

Here is my css:

```
.floating-button {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:  20px;
    z-index: 9999;
    right:  20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    color: white;
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to overcome the issue

Use keyboard plugin and on keyboard open and close change the css value of bottom, So on keyboard open it will automatically move floating button to up and on close move to down

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard --save

```
//Keyboard will be shown

window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', keyboardShowHandler);

function keyboardShowHandler(e){
    console.log('Keyboard height is: ' + e.keyboardHeight);
    $(".floating-button").css("bottom", e.keyboardHeight+"px"); 
    // You can use IONIC properties for this and change value as per your requierment
}

//Keyboard will hide

window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide', keyboardHideHandler);

function keyboardHideHandler(e){
    $(".floating-button").css("bottom", "20px");
}
```